# Using a C library with Python on Raspi

Tags: python, c, api, raspberry-pi3, sensors

I'm trying to use a time of flight sensor on a Raspi (Pololu VL53L1X) but there are no libraries for the sensor in python. The original manufacturer has provided with a C API for the sensor but I dont know how to use the API functions in my python code. Can someone help me understand what I can do use the sensor on Raspi without having to write the library from scratch? I've done some research and almost everyone suggests wrapping C libraries(API in this case?) in python but Im not sure how to do that. Any ideas or suggestions would be valuable.

P.S. There are libraries for the sensors for Arduino but I cant use Arduino and I need it to run on Raspi and using python if possible. I'm a beginner to Raspi and Python so a little explanation on your idea would be helpful.

Comment: Either [build a shim to interface between your C and python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html) or use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) to dynamically load the library and use the library

Comment: Find out more by using your favourite search engine and typing in "Call C function from python".

Comment: Can Ctypes be used to load API's? Because I have an API from the manufacturer written in C but I cant use this in python.

Comment: https://github.com/pimoroni/vl53l1x-python 
I did a google search and found this. there are instruction on how to install and use.

Comment: I tried to use the same library but it doesn't work, I tried the sample example in the GitHub but it only outputs the device info, rev number, general device data. I tried contacting the dev too but I received no response.

Comment: You need to enable i2c first.

Comment: I did, I enabled the I2C in Raspi cofiguration, I tested if the I2C was working with sudo i2cdetect -y 1 and its says I'm connected on 0x29 but I still cant get the sensor to output the data

Answer (score 1):

Making a simple python wrapper for a c library.

I got the following files in my work directory

**`mylib.c`** :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sumof(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

**`wrapper.py`** :

```
from ctypes import CDLL
so_file = "/path/to/my/work/dir/mylib.so"
my_c_lib = CDLL(so_file)

def sumof_fun(a,b):
    return my_c_lib.sumof(a,b)
```

As you can see we are using a shared library (`.so` file) in the python wrapper for creating that shared library we use following command:

**`$`**`gcc -fPIC -shared -o mylib.so mylib.c`

Now in python I could use following:

```
>>> import wrapper
>>> 
>>> wrapper.sumof_fun(4,5)
9
```

Ref: https://www.journaldev.com/31907/calling-c-functions-from-python

PS : But in your case I still believe its better to go for [pimoroni vl53l1x-python package](https://github.com/pimoroni/vl53l1x-python)

Comment: So this is what I've been trying to do for the last couple of hours, I create a shared object then import the created .o file to python and use a wrapper but the program I write doesn't read the shared object file, it throws in errors. I'll try working on it and post any updates/questions by tomorrow.